# Pi Zero 2 - Ubuntu Server 23.10 - HDMI doesn't work on TV

Tags: hdmi, ubuntu, pi-zero-w-2

I have a device all setup and it works on my AOC monitor, however when I connect the device to a TV or projector I see the first few seconds of terminal output as ubuntu boots up, then the screen cuts out and I get the No Device Connected error from my TV or Projector.

Any idea why this works fine on a monitor but not a television or projector?

I remember having a similar issue on my Pi 3 when I built it out as a retro pi and the fix then was to set the following options in `/boot/config.txt`:

```
hdmi_force_hotplug=1
hdmi_group=1
hdmi_mode=31
```

I tried adding those to `/boot/firmware/config.txt` and still no luck. I verified that my working pi 3 does in fact work on the same device I'm testing the zero on, so it should be possible, but I'm missing something.

Any help is appreciated.

Specs:
Pi zero 2
Ubuntu Server 23.10

Comment: probably because a TV is not a monitor ... exploring the difference may lead to an answer

Answer (score 0):

On a hunch I tried a different power adapter and that fixed the issue. I have no clue why, but I switched from a micro usb that had a wall plug hard wired to it (that didn't work), to a regular micro usb cable plugged into a brick (That worked!).